# How can I recognize a wildcard for the purpose of arbitrary search?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS-based Bot Framework bot up and running and I would like to add the ability to allow the user to perform a search. For example I would like the user to utter:

> help me find cheap hotels in Paris

or

> search for images of the moon landing

I would like to recognize that the user is performing a search intent, which is easy enough. The hard part is setting up LUIS to provide the arbitrary search terms. I want to take those terms and feed them to a Bing or Google search (or just against my own Azure Search instance). How do I coax LUIS into giving me the string "cheap hotels in Paris" or "images of the moon landing"?

Comment: I'm sorry, wasn't able to understand the hard part. The problem is just how to get the exact sentence the user entered?

Comment: Well, I just want to extract the part of the sentence that I can send to the search engine. So if the sentence was "do a search for antique cars" I just want the string "antique cars". I don't want the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood this correctly, that's what entities are for. Let's say you have the intent MakeSearch that's supposed to recognize utterances such as

> help me find cheap hotels in Paris

or

> search for images of the moon landing

You could create a Entity called `SearchItem`, and when training you `MakeSearch` intent you should select ***"cheap hotels in Paris"*** and ***"images of the moon landing"*** as being `SearchItem` entities.

Then inside your `LuisDialog`, in the intent handler methods you could extract the `Entity` from the `LuisResult`.

Just one example of how you could this in the code:

```
result.Entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "SearchItem").Entity;
```

Comment: OK, this is a good idea to try. Do you think I could create an entity that is flexible enough to match anything the user enters?

Comment: With enough training I think it could work. The value of the entity will be very different for each query, but the way people search for stuff follow a pattern that I think would allow this to work, for example if you train the model enough it will recognize the context and the text that comes after "search for", or "help me find" will be treated as being part of the SearchItem entity.

Comment: That would be perfect. I'll try this out and report back.

Comment: @elabs: How successful was this for you?